# Amend ContentSearch settings to a single index?

Tags: content-search, indexing, index, settings

I have a bunch of custom indexes and I need to finetune only 1 of them, not affecting the others. Let's say, I want to change `ContentSearch.Update.BatchSize`, is there a way to apply this setting for 1 particular index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible out of the box.

`SolrContextFactory` class, which is responsible for creating `IProviderUpdateContect` implementation object, checks if batch mode is enabled for indexing, by checking

```
`Settings.GetBoolSetting("ContentSearch.Update.BatchModeEnabled")`
```

If it's not enabled, it creates an object of `SolrUpdateContext`.

And if it's enabled, it creates an object of `SolrBatchUpdateContext` class with batch size read from configuration - `ContentSearch.Update.BatchSize`.

There is no place there for getting batch size for a single index, unless you create a new implementation of `AbstractContextFactory` and override `GetUpdateContext` method to return index-specific batch size.